# How to select data from multiple dataframes

Tags: numpy, pandas

I'm beginner on pandas i have to dataframes first called
DATA_DF which contains many fields and i'm interested for `DATA_DF['Date effet']` as type datetime
and i have other dataframe called TAUX_DF contains years and every year has a value

```
TAUX_DF =
Année   <10 ans >10 ans
1987    2,8168% 3,4664%
1988    2,8168% 3,4664%
1989    2,8168% 3,4664%
1990    2,8168% 3,4664%
```

i want to create new column on DATA_DF called "DATA_DF['Taux technique']"
it take from `DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year` compare it with the year on `TAUX_DF['Année']` and put value like this on Excel

```
=SI(G5>120;RECHERCHEV(ANNEE(C5);Taux!$A$2:$C$29;3;FAUX);RECHERCHEV(ANNEE(C5);Taux!$A$2:$C$29;2;FAUX))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATA_DF['Année'] = DATA_DF['Date effet'].dt.year ## ==> make column with year of the data_df in order to compare (merge) it later on with the 'TAUX_DF'.

DATA_DF = pd.merge(DATA_DF,TAUX_DF,left_on='Année',right_on='Année', how='left')
```

Comment: Please Mr i want to ask you more i have another field on DATA_DF called Duration in months DATA_DF['duration'] contains number of months i want to do condition to take the value of TAUX_DF if it's <10 years takes the value on the field TAUX_DF ['<10 ans'] else TAUX_DF ['>10 ans'] Cordially